# identical md5 png files: one looks blurry in android app and the other looks crisp

Tags: java, android

Android dev is making an app via designs uploaded to Zeplin (made with sketch).

Developer is saying that images exported directly from Sketch look crisp, while images downloaded from Zeplin don't.

**I've hard time believing this, as png is png.**

1. I first looked at file sizes and confirmed that both Zeplin downloads and Sketch exports are identical byte sized.
2. Than I ran md5 over both and confirmed that hashes match, and indeed they do!
3. I also went ahead and confirmed hex data is identical manually (xxd in osx) in case md5 algorithm was producing wrong identical hashes for diff data.

So what gives? why do sketch images look crisp and zeplin ones blurry as they are identical md5/hesh/size wise?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d1qegrte20osxwi/Zeplin.zip?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4fldj0zw9w5aern/Sketch.zip?dl=0

[image: zeplin]
[image]

Comment: Well they look both the same! Don't they?

Comment: @greenapps yes! they are identical. But dev is saying they don't look same in android app. I'm trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Then you should show the Android code that downloads the .png and that displays it. You can ruin a lot if you download png's in the wrong way. You should compare file sizes in the Android app. Not somewhere on your servers. Extract the files from the Android device and then compare.